Powershell - Redirect InvalidArgument Error Output to File
The (invalid) command New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress 172.1.2.3 -PrefixLengh 27 produces the following error:
New-NetIPAddress : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'PrefixLengh'.
At line:1 char:65
+ ... ddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress 172.1.2.3 -PrefixLengh 27
+                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-NetIPAddress], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,New-NetIPAddress

I want to redirect this error message to a file.
Usually, this should work somewhat like this: New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress 172.1.2.3 -PrefixLengh 27 2>&1 > output
I have tried lots of combinations, for example *> out, 2>&1 3>&1 4>&1 5>&1 6>&1 > out, but none of them redirect the output. It always gets printed to the screen and the file remains empty. PSVersion: 5.1.22621.2506 (latest powershell on windows 11).
How can I properly redirect this error output to a file?

you're getting a parameterbinding exception, you need to use a try catch there as this is a terminating error

Why would you not correct the invalid command?

@lit I am running commands remotely through a special mechanism (vmware_vm_shell ansible module) and somehow need to see the output, including errors like this. In this case, I of course fixed the incorrect parameter.

The ParameterBindingException is a statement terminating error, you can't redirect it in this case. You need to use try \ catch statement. See Everything you wanted to know about exceptions for in-depth details about error handling in PowerShell.
try {
    New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress 172.1.2.3 -PrefixLengh 27
}
catch {
    $_ | Out-File path\to\output
}


Regarding the follow-up comment, if there is a way to do this without try \ catch. The answer is yes, it depends, in this case you could wrap the statement in a scriptblock and invoke it in the same statement. This would allow redirection. However it's worth noting this will not always work, i.e. in the case of a throw.
& { New-NetIPAddress -InterfaceAlias Ethernet0 -IPAddress 172.1.2.3 -PrefixLengh 27 } *> path\to\output


I kind of need to do this within a single command (may include pipes) due to constraints of the execution environment (which is why I need this to log to a file in the first case..). Is there any solution to do this within a single command (without try/catch scriptblocks)?

@Zulakis is it always cmdlets that you're running? you could redirect this kind of error by wrapping it in a scriptblock (no try / catch needed) could even make a little function to redirect to a file. however if there is an actual throw then you must a try / catch.

@Zulakis added an update
